# How to fit a list of images in an HTML div to form a 2D grid?

Tags: javascript, html, css, knockout.js

EDIT: Problem fixed. See my own answer for details. Will mark it as the answer in 2 days when SO lets me.

I am populating a div with a list of square images using Knockout. The div is currently of fixed width and height, though will eventually be resizeable. I would like the images to fill up the div row by row. So when image n reaches the boundaries of the div's width, image n+1 is wrapped around to the next row. Currently, the images flow over the boundaries of the div to fill the entire window.

The current markup is as follows:

```
<div data-bind="foreach: images" width="500" height="500">
    <img data-bind="attr: { src: fileName }">
</div>
```

I've played around with `float` and `overflow` with no success so far. I've also tried putting the images in their own divs. The images exhibit the wrapping behaviour I want in the whole window to form a grid, just not in the div I've put them in.

How do I make the images stay inside the div while getting the grid that I want? Is this possible with HTML/CSS alone or does it require some Javascript?

Comment: Using floats is the way to go. What's your CSS look like?

Comment: Problem fixed. Only needed to add `float: left` to each image. My issue was not specifying the length unit of the container's width. Will mark my own answer in 2 days when SO lets me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was that I was not specifying the length units for my containing div. In my original markup, I was using the HTML attribute `width="500"`. Changing this to inline CSS and specifying the length unit solved the problem, keeping my 2D grid inside the div: `style="width: 500px"`

Besides this, as suggested by wahwahwah, the following style was required for a containing div for each image: `float: left;`

Inlining the CSS, the end result is:

```
 <div data-bind="foreach: images" style="width: 500px">
     <div style="float: left;">
          <img data-bind="attr: { src: fileName }">
     </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

As Daniel Weiner said in his comment - floats are the way to go. Add in `display : inline-block;` to keep each element aligned. Example:

```css
#container {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: black;
  display: inline-block;
}
.block {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: #fff;
  margin: 10px;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div id=container>
  <div class="block">1</div>
  <div class="block">2</div>
  <div class="block">3</div>
  <div class="block">4</div>
  <div class="block">5</div>
  <div class="block">6</div>
  <div class="block">7</div>
  <div class="block">8</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried `float: left` beforehand and this did not work. However, I've solved the problem - the issue was something unrelated! I was setting the width of my container via the HTML attribute. Changing it to the CSS equivalent and adding some units (px in this case) got the desired result. Not specifying the length units for the container appears to be the issue. `float: left` was still required though, so thanks for your contribution.